# ValueError: too many values

Tags: python, unpack, valueerror

I am going through a python tutorial.  I typed in exactly what the tutorial has but it won't run.  I think the issue is the tutorial uses Python 2 something  and i am using Python 3.5. For instance the tutorial does not use parenthesis after the print and i have to and it uses raw_input where i use just input.

This is what i am trying to run-

```
def sumProblem(x, y): 
    print ('The sum of %s and %s is %s.' % (x, y, x+y))


def main(): 
    sumProblem(2, 3) 
    sumProblem(1234567890123, 535790269358) 
    a, b = input("Enter two comma separated numbers: ") 
    sumProblem(a, b)


main()
```

This is the error i receive:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If i put just two numbers with out  a comma it will concatenate them.  I have tried to change to integer but it gives this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

When i searched it on here the answers did not seem to apply to my problem, they were much more involved or i didn't understand.

Comment: Hi @David! Please provide full stacktrace: it's easier to work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input(..)` returns a *string*. A string is an iterable, so you *can* unpack this with:

```
a, b = input("Enter two comma separated numbers: ")
```

but only if the string contains exactly *two* items. So for a string this means that the string contains exactly two characters.

The code however hints that you want to input two integers. We can use `str.split()` to split the string into a list of "words".

We then can perform a `map`ping with `int` as function:

```
def sumProblem(x, y): 
    print ('The sum of %s and %s is %s.' % (x, y, x+y))
def main(): 
    sumProblem(2, 3) 
    sumProblem(1234567890123, 535790269358) 
    a, b = map(int, input("Enter two comma separated numbers: ").split(','))
    sumProblem(a, b)
main()
```

Comment: @chepner: yes, I somehow realized that at the same time, thanks.

Comment: @chepner:  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Your input should look like this:

```
a, b = map(int, input('text:').split(','))
```

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a single line of input - a string. Parsing it is left to you.